# Deployment with windeployqt: additional dlls

Tags: qt

I'm trying to deploy additional dlls with windeployqt on build. I would like to do this with out adding these 'extra's to the qt/bin folder.

Is there a way to tell windeployqt to grab from additional folders for dependencies?

I have looked around and cannot find the answer I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dll resolution looks in a few different locations.  If your exe can find the dlls then it should be happy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

The plugins folders are different.  Those are looked for using the library search paths that the `QApplication` sets up.  It is usually easiest to place these folders right next to the exe, but you can put them other places, if you put the correct line in your main.cpp to tell the application to look in those other places.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#setLibraryPaths

Hope that helps.